# In matlab, when I used eval and sprintf (variable%d), why can't the line containe two different variables that utilize %d?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, eval, cell, printf

Here's an example:

```
for b = 1:numcarlo;
eval(sprintf('pspsdist%d = psdistmat(b,:);', b))
eval(sprintf('cell%d = cell(1, iterestemp%d);', b))
end;
```

Line 1 works, it tells us how many times to execute in the for loop.  Line 2 works, it generates numcarlo numbers of pspsdist with the number as a suffix (pspsdist1, etc).
Line 3 *doesn't work* as long as iterestemp has a %d at the end.  It provides the following error:

```
??? Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

But it's balanced!  When I get rid of that %d, it works, but I need to have iterestemp%d because there are multiple iterestemps with suffixes (as in pspsdist, they are numbered at the end and I refer to a specific one).

Why does matlab do this and is there any way around this?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you need to rethink the way you're attacking your problem. Why use `variable%d` and `eval` when you can simply index into an array `variable`? The use of `eval` should limited to somewhere between `never` and `not at all`. (Unless you know what you're doing and understand when to break the rules.)

Comment: Do NOT use `eval()`! Bad data management, big headaches, uninteresting forum questions.

Comment: Hi all.  I have already read that I probably shouldn't use it, but I just started using matlab and don't really have time to do things 'the right way'.  I'm sort of forced to piece it together as I go and so far it works the way I like it to.  If my advisor doesn't complain, then everything is hunky-dory.  Since he's not an expert coder (he's picked as he's gone through his career as well), I suspect nothing is wrong.  

I'm considering marking your comments as unconstructive , since they don't offer a direct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `%d` needs its own argument.  Try this:

```
eval(sprintf('cell%d = cell(1, iterestemp%d);', b, b))
```

(But really you should be using arrays of some sort. I'd like to give more specific advice but I don't really know Matlab.)

Answer (score 2):

You've already said you're not interested in learning how to write better code, but this is Stack Overflow, where questions are supposed to help other people readers as well.  So for others who are interested:  Use a cell array instead of a dynamically-named variable, and the whole problem goes away.  Plus MATLAB can optimize your code, and you'll be able to read it 3 months from now.

```
for b = 1:numcarlo;
    pspsdist{b} = psdistmat(b,:);
    mycell{b}= cell(1, iterestemp{b});
end
```

Comment: Hi.  I didn't say that I'm not interesting in learning how to write better code.  You're sort of putting words in my mouth.  However, your answer is helpful in getting me to understand the power of arrays, and I will apply this solution going forward.